# Maintain responsive design while giving min-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive web page and i have done most of the parts correctly but i have trouble in certain areas.

1. I want to stop resizing the contents when i change the size of the browser windows.
   For that i have used `min-width`
2. The issue is when i see the responsive layout for ex: iPad, the layout is capped for the `min-width` i have set. Without the `min-width` my responsive design works correctly.
3. How can i stop resizing contents while browser resizing but maintain correct layout for ex: ipad or other tabs.
4. Ex: Facebook does this correctly.

my css

```
.body_clr {

    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1129px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT";

}

.container_body {

    width: 1130px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1139px) {

    .container_body {

        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;

    }

    .body_clr {

        overflow-x: auto;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;

    }
}
```

Html

```
   <div className="body_clr">

            <div className="container_body">

                            <div className="Left">

                                <LeftNav/>

                            </div>

                            <div className="Left">

                                <MiddleNav/>

                            </div>

                            <div className="Left">

                                <RightNav/>

                            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use max-width property. max-width:100%

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){
        $('.body_clr').css('min-width','100%');
    }
    else {
        $('.body_clr').css('min-width','1129px');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you are not strict to HTML and CSS, try out this jQuery may helpful